# execute a shell script against a list of arguments from the terminal

Tags: bash, ksh

occasionally, but not often enough to need to write a script for it, i may need to run 'foo' against a set of arguments.  It may vary which argument is static vs which is a list, and it may vary the length of the list.

to illustrate what i am trying to do, please consider

`rm ./$(ls -lrt foo | awk '{print $9}')`

as a demonstration of the same functionality i am trying to achieve (excepting of course this syntax rm is interactive, the script in question would not be, but `rm` performs action against the set of args given to it) instead of, eg

`foo 1 2a 3; foo 1 2b 3; foo 1 2c 3`

is there some syntax from the terminal (this system has access to either ksh88 or bash) that I could for instance

`foo 1 $(2a,2b,2c) 3`

or similar, such that i could enter once the script and constant args and automate only the part that is needed in the moment?  the args needed may or may not be sequential or otherwise a pattern that would make sense to use a for loop.  So i would be listing, whether csv or some other kind of way each one explicitly without being able to provide it via the output of any other command.

I am sure any shell is capable of doing what i intend i just don't have a way to test what might work outside of production.

thanks in advance.

edit: to 2a-2c may not have illustrated as precisely, the arg could have been (apple,banana,orange) ie they are not necessarily 2(a..c) in such simple terms.

Comment: `echo 1 2{a,b,c} 3` => `1 2a 2b 2c 3`, so perhaps try `foo 1 2{a,b,c} 3` ?  if this doesn't address your issue then we'll need more details and/or examples

Comment: Granted this doesn't answer your question, but as a note, `rm ./$(ls -lrt foo | awk '{print $9}')` is a rather serious antipattern -- fails badly with filenames with spaces, isn't guaranteed to work at all across the entire range of POSIX-compliant `ls` implementations, etc. See also [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Comment: Soooo `for i in a b c; do foo 1 2$i 3; done`?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you for that info. i was only using it for illustrative purposes as the fact that that worked prompted me to consider how much smarter i can be with input data without having to make as many scripts and functions for infrequent or one off situations.

Comment: Note: [don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple shell loop:

```sh
for arg in apple banana orange; do
    foo 1 "$arg" 3
done
```

or a while-read loop:

```sh
some_process_that_generates_arguments | while IFS= read -r line; do
    foo 1 "$line" 3
done

# usually better to write that like this:
while IFS= read -r line; do
    foo 1 "$line" 3
done < <(some_process_that_generates_arguments)
```

Or with `xargs`

```sh
some_process_that_generates_arguments | xargs -I ARG foo 1 ARG 3
```

demo

```sh
$ seq 5 8 | xargs -I ARG echo first ARG last
first 5 last
first 6 last
first 7 last
first 8 last
```

---

In your question, using `ls` indicates you want to do stuff with files. `ls` is the wrong tool for that: you should either use shell globs or `find`.

Assuming you want to find all *files* under directory "foo":

```sh
shopt -s globstar nullglob
for path in foo/**; do
    [[ -f $path ]] || continue
    do_something_with "$path"
done
```

or

```sh
find foo -type f -exec do_something_with '{}' \;
```

Comment: the for would definitely work, just a bit much in one line.  in this case xargs would not help but that is something i have noted for the future. assuming there isn't some other epiphany this is probably what i am going to have to stick with so thank you.